# statusbar issue with splash screen and navigation screen

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, splash-screen, statusbar

I have an issue with statusbar and it's like when i start my app and splash screen appears with some delay so splash screen stays upto few seconds at that time i've hide the statusbar but at the end of that delay i've make my view controller visible with statusbar and having this type of issue please see screenshot and help me out thanks :)

[image: Splash Screen] [image: after removal of splash screen]

Comment: put code of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` or how u add rootViewController ??

Comment: Hope you have set Status bar is initially hidden" value set to YES in your info.plist..

Comment: @iPatel : no need of code every thing is clear i've just hide and show the statusbar as usual.

Comment: @Nilesh Patel yes i have hide the statusbar from the settings of project from xcode and then shown it programmatically.

Comment: your navigation controller is over wrapping nothing else just check your rootViewController  howz u added ??

Comment: it's also as usual manner like this:- [self.window setRootViewController:self.navMain];.